# Unknown escape sequence "\040" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string

I need to replace something like "abc%20def%20xyz" with "abc\ def\ xyz".
I used this function that works fine.

```
string2 =[string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"\ "];
```

However, I got warning saying

`Unknown escape sequence "\040"`.

What's wrong with this, and how can I remove this  warning?

Answer (score 7):

The backslash in the end string is escaping the space character, which isn't valid. To do what you want, you need to escape the backslash:

`string2 =[string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"\\ "];`